# SceneKit custom geometry produces “double not supported” / “invalid vertex format” runtime error

Tags: swift, scenekit

I don't understand what's wrong with the following code:

```
class Terrain {

    private class func createGeometry () -> SCNGeometry {

        let sources = [
            SCNGeometrySource(vertices:[
                SCNVector3(x: -1.0, y: -1.0, z:  0.0),
                SCNVector3(x: -1.0, y:  1.0, z:  0.0),
                SCNVector3(x:  1.0, y:  1.0, z:  0.0),
                SCNVector3(x:  1.0, y: -1.0, z:  0.0)], count:4),
            SCNGeometrySource(normals:[
                SCNVector3(x:  0.0, y:  0.0, z: -1.0),
                SCNVector3(x:  0.0, y:  0.0, z: -1.0),
                SCNVector3(x:  0.0, y:  0.0, z: -1.0),
                SCNVector3(x:  0.0, y:  0.0, z: -1.0)], count:4),
            SCNGeometrySource(textureCoordinates:[
                CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0),
                CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0),
                CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0),
                CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)], count:4)
        ]

        let elements = [
            SCNGeometryElement(indices: [0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2], primitiveType: .Triangles)
        ]

        let geo = SCNGeometry(sources:sources, elements:elements)

        let mat = SCNMaterial()
        mat.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()
        mat.doubleSided = true
        geo.materials = [mat, mat]


        return geo
    }

    class func createNode () -> SCNNode {

        let node = SCNNode(geometry: createGeometry())
        node.name = "Terrain"
        node.position = SCNVector3()
        return node
    }
}
```

I use it as follows:

```
   let terrain = Terrain.createNode()
   sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(terrain)
```

But get:

```
2016-01-19 22:21:17.600 SceneKit: error, C3DRendererContextSetupResidentMeshSourceAtLocation - double not supported
2016-01-19 22:21:17.601 SceneKit: error, C3DSourceAccessorToVertexFormat - invalid vertex format
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Metal/Metal-55.2.6.1/Framework/MTLVertexDescriptor.mm:761: failed assertion `Unused buffer at index 18.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the geometry is expecting `float` components but you’re giving it `double`s—CGPoint’s components are CGFloat values, which are typedef’d to `double` on 64-bit systems. Unfortunately, the SCNGeometrySource `…textureCoordinates:` initializer insists on CGPoints, so you can’t use that; the workaround I found was to create an NSData wrapping an array of [SIMD float vectors](http://www.russbishop.net/swift-2-simd), then use the much longer [`data:semantic:etc:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNGeometrySource_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SCNGeometrySource/geometrySourceWithData:semantic:vectorCount:floatComponents:componentsPerVector:bytesPerComponent:dataOffset:dataStride:) initializer to consume the data. Something like this should do the trick:

```
let coordinates = [float2(0, 0), float2(0, 1), float2(1, 1), float2(1, 0)]
let coordinateData = NSData(bytes:coordinates, length:4 * sizeof(float2))
let coordinateSource = SCNGeometrySource(data: coordinateData,
                                     semantic: SCNGeometrySourceSemanticTexcoord,
                                  vectorCount: 4,
                              floatComponents: true,
                          componentsPerVector: 2,
                            bytesPerComponent: sizeof(Float),
                                   dataOffset: 0,
                                   dataStride: sizeof(float2))
```

Comment: By using the way you set the texture coord (or by removing texturecoord in the elements) my code does not break anymore. Good. But it draws nothing on screen. I asked this specific question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897040/scenekit-custom-geometry-does-not-show-up